# GStreamer Error While Streaming to AWS Kinesis on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, embedded, gstreamer

I'm diving into the world of streaming with GStreamer on a Raspberry Pi to AWS Kinesis, and I've hit a roadblock. I'm encountering the following error:

(kvsWebrtcClientMasterGstSample:246): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered: assertion 'types != 0' failed

i gave correct access key ,secret key ,all dependencies, credentials and certificate path but the issue is persistent

Has anyone else faced this issue? If so, could you share some insights on how to tackle it? I'm eager to get past this hurdle and continue with my streaming project.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: 1) It would be useful to see the pipeline you're using. 2) Did you set `GST_DEBUG` env variable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.